# Photon S DLP first layers adhere but support will not

Tags: sla, dlp

Recently I changed the FEP bottom of my Anycubic Photon S and I'm having problems with prints now. The bottom layer sticks super well, but none of the supports or the prints do.

I've tried tensioning the vat, releveling, and changed supports of the structure. Nothing works and I don't know how to proceed.

I also tried tightening all of the screws on the build plate, but still errors.

I'm using Anycubic black resin, 8 bottom layers at 90 seconds, 7 second exposure with 2 seconds off.

The image shows a failed print example:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to a) increase exposure b) lay a print flat against the surface (like a test-u or something) c) releveling the bed after the swap?

Comment: @Trish I had tried increasing exposure and releveling. I tried printing flat against the surface and it worked! Does that just mean that I need to add more supports to what I'm printing? My supports already seem pretty dense, so I'd love to know of another way to prevent this from happening

Comment: I've also been having bad luck replicating it. When I changed files nothing worked again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally reached out to anycubic and their tech support answered and was awesome!

They had me update the firmware, tighten the fep film more ( instead of using the small lever I used the big lever this time), then level the bed again. I printed their test print and it worked!

After that I looked at their parameters and I saw that mine were very different. The main differences was in the lift distance, speed and retract speed. I only had 1 mm lift distance and much slower.

Here are the correct ones in the end

[image: true parameters]

Comment: Many thanks for answering your question! Please accept after 48 hours.